# Facets for nested tree with ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation, facet

I'm new to ElasticSearch, so I need some help with it.

I have a query to search for `products` which can belong to many `categories`. `Categories` are combined in a nested tree.

Example data:

```
categories: [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'First category',
    categories:[
      {
        id: 12,
        name: 'First subcategory'
      },
      {
        id: 13,
        name: 'Second subcategory'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Second category'
  }
],
products: [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'First product',
    categories_ids: [2, 12]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Second product',
    categories_ids: [1]
  }
]
```

Besides the search results I need to get the `categories` tree including the number of search results in each `category` (excluding categories without any search results).

For the above example it should be:

- First category (2)

  - First subcategory (1)
- Second category (1)

Can someone explain how to do this using ElasticSearch's aggregations?

Thanks.

Comment: How many category levels do you have?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar need and used Nested objects. Here is that thread

[How to narrow down the current aggregation context to a specific scope within set of documents returned from Filter Aggregation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32642842/how-to-narrow-down-the-current-aggregation-context-to-a-specific-scope-within-se)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are in search for something around this:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "category_agg": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "category_name"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "sub_category_agg": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "sub_category"
          },
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "sub_category": "First subcategory"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Apply filters (or omit) as on need and be sure the fields on which you make aggregations (category_name and subcategory_name in this example) to be not_analyzed.