# How to narrow down the current aggregation context to a specific scope within set of documents returned from Filter Aggregation?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a nested object mapping, the sample data:

```
     {
        "_index": "simpleindex",
        "_type": "games",
        "_id": "AU_eC-Uzt6KxlUliF68N",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
           "continents": [
              {
                 "name": "Asia",
                 "countries": [
                    {
                       "name": "India",
                       "states": [
                          {
                             "name": "TN",
                             "game": "soccor",
                             "wins": 1
                          }
                       ]
                    },
                    {
                       "name": "India",
                       "states": [
                          {
                             "name": "KA",
                             "game": "soccor",
                             "wins": 1
                          }
                       ]
                    }
                 ]
              }
           ]
        }
     },
     {
        "_index": "simpleindex",
        "_type": "games",
        "_id": "AU_eCf5dt6KxlUliF637",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
           "continents": [
              {
                 "name": "Asia",
                 "countries": [
                    {
                       "name": "India",
                       "states": [
                          {
                             "name": "TN",
                             "game": "soccor",
                             "wins": 1
                          }
                       ]
                    }
                 ]
              }
           ]
        }
     },
     {
        "_index": "simpleindex",
        "_type": "games",
        "_id": "AU_eDIdXt6KxlUliF69i",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
           "continents": [
              {
                 "name": "Asia",
                 "countries": [
                    {
                       "name": "India",
                       "states": [
                          {
                             "name": "TN",
                             "game": "soccor",
                             "wins": 1
                          }
                       ]
                    },
                    {
                       "name": "India",
                       "states": [
                          {
                             "name": "KA",
                             "game": "soccor",
                             "wins": 1
                          }
                       ]
                    },
                    {
                       "name": "Pak",
                       "states": [
                          {
                             "name": "NA",
                             "game": "soccor",
                             "wins": 1
                          }
                       ]
                    }
                 ]
              }
           ]
        }
     }
```

Here is my Filtered Aggregation that returns documents that matches the filter criteria (i.e. continent should be 'Asia' AND country should be 'India'):

```
{
"aggs": {
"DocumentSet": {
  "filter": {
    "and": {
      "filters": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "continents",
            "query": {
              "match": {
                "continents.name": "asia"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "continents.countries",
            "query": {
              "match": {
                "continents.countries.name": "india"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "continents": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "continents"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "countries": {
          "nested": {
            "path": "continents.countries"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "states": {
              "nested": {
                "path": "continents.countries.states"
              },
              "aggs": {
                "count": {
                  "value_count": {
                    "field": "continents.countries.states.wins"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}}}
```

And here is the result (copy pasted only the aggregation here):

```
"aggregations": {
  "DocumentSet": {
     "doc_count": 3,
     "continents": {
         "doc_count": 3,
         "countries": {
            "doc_count": 6,
            "states": {
               "doc_count": 6,
               "count": {
                  "value": 6
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

My intention is to get "wins" only from `continents.name=asia AND countries.name=india`. The filter works as expected but I need to narrow down the aggregation scope only to `countries.name=india`; essentially another level of scope on the docs returned by Filter aggregation so that leaf aggregation count is 5 instead of 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this aggregation:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "continents": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "continents"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "asia_continent": {
          "filter": {
            "query": {
              "match": {
                "continents.name": "asia"
              }
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "countries": {
              "nested": {
                "path": "continents.countries"
              },
              "aggs": {
                "india_country": {
                  "filter": {
                    "query": {
                      "match": {
                        "continents.countries.name": "india"
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "aggs": {
                    "states": {
                      "nested": {
                        "path": "continents.countries.states"
                      },
                      "aggs": {
                        "count": {
                          "value_count": {
                            "field": "continents.countries.states.wins"
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The way we solved this problem is by sending the ids of the smallest items in the tree of categories.
For example, if your tree is : 
continent
  country

There aren't many countries, so you can just filter based on whatever the user selected. For example if the user selected Europe => France and Asia => India and China, you filter by the ids of these 3 countries. Then your aggregation looks like above except you don't have to have these filters inside the aggregation. 
This only works for certain use cases though.